# Unescape LaTeX to UTF-8 or ASCII

Tags: r, encoding, latex, character

I use the R packages `RefManageR` and `bibtex` packages to read in a bibtex file I exported from Mendeley (my reference manager). Sometimes authors are listed with accents in their name (López), but in BibTeX these are escaped to `"L{\\'{o}}pez"`. However, in another reference this name is spelled without accent (Lopez).

How can I parse the `"L{\\'{o}}pez"` to `López` or `Lopez` so I can compare them?
I googled but this only shows how I can escape -while I want to unescape- or to make pdf's from R.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked for me, but I still think there must be a better solution:

```
deTeX <- function(x) {
    gsub("\\{\\\\.+?\\{([a-z]*)\\}\\}", "\\1", x, fixed = FALSE, perl = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)
}
```